# Function as an argument of another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm learning this language hence I'm new with Python. The code is:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def double_add(x, a, b):
    return x(x(a, b), x(a, b))

a = 4
b = 5
print(double_add(add, a, b))
```

The `add` function is simple, it adds two numbers. The `double_add` function has three arguments. I understand what is happening (With some doubts). The result is `18`. I can't understand how `double_add` uses `add` to function.

The question is, what is the connection between these two functions?

It would be helpful if tell me some examples of using a function as an argument of another function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `add` function is being passed as `x`. `x(a,b)` is basically `add(a,b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is an object just like any other in Python. So you can pass it as argument, assign attributes to it, and well maybe most importantely - call it. We can look at a simpler example to understand how passing a function works:

```py
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

def operate(func, a, b):
    return func(a, b)

a = 4
b = 5
print(operate(add, a, b))  
print(operate(sub, a, b))
operate(print, a, b)
```

And this prints out:

```
9
-1
4 5
```

That is because in each case, `func` is assigned with the respective **function object** passed as an argument, and then by doing `func(a, b)` it actually **calls** that function on the given arguments.

---

So what happens with your line:

```
return x(x(a, b), x(a, b))
```

is first both `x(a, b)` are evaluated as `add(4, 5)` which gives `9`. And then the outer `x(...)` is evaluated as `add(9, 9)` which gives `18`.

Comment: "*That is because in each case, func is assigned with the respective function object, and then when doing func(a, b) it actually calls that function on the given arguments.*", this line is what I was looking for. Thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 4):

In `python` language, functions (and methods) are [first class objects](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/first-class-functions-in-python). `First Class` objects are those objects, which can be handled uniformly.

So, you just pass a `method` as an *argument*.

Your method will return `add(add(4, 5), add(4, 5))` which is `add(9, 9)` and it's equals to `18`.

Answer (score 1):

[Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) are objects in Python, just like anything else such as lists, strings.. and you can pass them same way you do with variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you would add `print(x)` in the `double_add` function you would see that it would print `<function add at 0x10dd12290>`. 
Therefore, the code of `double_add` is basically the same as if you would do following:

```py
print(add(add(a,b), add(a,b))) # returns 18 in your case
```

Answer (score 0):

The function object `add` is passed as an argument to `double_add`, where it is locally referred to as `x`. `x` is then called on each, and then on the two return values from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def double_add(x, a, b):
    return x(x(a, b), x(a, b))
```

Let's write it differently so it's easier to explain:

```
def double_add(x, a, b):
    result1 = x(a, b)
    result2 = x(a, b)
    return x(result1, result2)
```

This means, take the function `x`, and apply it to the parameters `a` and `b`. `x` could be whatever function here.

```
print(double_add(add, a, b))
```

Then this means: call the `double_add` function`, giving it`add`as the first parameter. So`double_add`, would do:

```
result1 = add(a, b)
result2 = add(a, b)
return add(result1, result2)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a very simple example of what is called "dependency injection". What it means is that you are not explicitly defining an interaction between the two functions, instead you are defining that `double_add` should use some function, but it only knows what it is when the code is actually run. (At runtime you are *injecting* the depedency on a specific function, instead of hardcoding it in the function itself),

Try for example the following

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b

def double_add(x, a, b):
    return x(x(a, b), x(a, b))

a = 4
b = 5

print(double_add(add, a, b))  
print(double_add(subtract, a, b))
```

In other words, `double_add` has become a generic function that will execute whatever you give it twice and print the result